# Mandrill text field character limit PHP

Tags: php, email, mandrill, string-length

I am trying to send a simple email using [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) and everything works well until I put too much text into the text field, here is what I mean:

```
$message = array(
    'subject' => $subject,
    'text' => $content,
    'from_email' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => $toMail,
        )
    )
);

$mandrill->messages->send($message, $async=false, $ip_pool=null, $send_at=null);
```

So when $content contains more than about 1000 characters the email does not send and I get a 500 error, which seems to be an API timeout. However I need to send emails with up to 20000 characters in them. Has this happened to anyone? Also this worked a couple months ago for me, I am not sure why it does not work anymore.

I saw that SMTP headers can only be 1000 characters long, but the text segment doesn't land in the header does it?

UPDATE: So interestingly enough, it still works fine on my main computer. I moved the website to another machine running ubuntu 14.04 and that is where the error started appearing. Anybody have any ideas as to why?

Comment: Tray change `'text' => $content` by `'html' => $content`

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't do anything :/

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support? Usually they respond to issues in within 2 hours...

Comment: I think you can only do that if you pay.. and I don't unfortunetaly

Comment: For anybody also having this weird issue, I just reinstalled my ubuntu machine and solved my problem that way.